# Pandas saving and reading DataFrame to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to save a pandas DataFrame with some dates to json and then read it back. Although when I'm reading back from json I'm getting the dates a different format (which most of the time required parse the dates again).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(range(7),pd.date_range('2014-10-01','2014-10-07')).reset_index()
df.columns = ['LoadDate','number']
print df

    LoadDate  number
0 2014-10-01       0
1 2014-10-02       1
2 2014-10-03       2
3 2014-10-04       3
4 2014-10-05       4
5 2014-10-06       5
6 2014-10-07       6
```

Now, if I'm exporting to and the reading back and I'll get the following results (unwanted)

```
print pd.read_json(df.to_json())

        LoadDate  number
0  1412121600000       0
1  1412208000000       1
2  1412294400000       2
3  1412380800000       3
4  1412467200000       4
5  1412553600000       5
6  1412640000000       6
```

I'd like to be able to read back the date in the original format. How can I do this in a clean way?

Here come the funny part.

```
df.columns = ['date','number']
print pd.read_json(df.to_json())

        date  number
0 2014-10-01       0
1 2014-10-02       1
2 2014-10-03       2
3 2014-10-04       3
4 2014-10-05       4
5 2014-10-06       5
6 2014-10-07       6
```

If I change the name of the column to "date", it works! Of course, I'd like to be able to call the column something different from date, so I'm still interested in figured out how can I manage this. Many thanks! (I'm using pandas 0.15.0!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the reason you get these numbers when using `to_json`. The [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) says that "datetime objects will be converted to UNIX timestamps":

```
In [27]: df.to_json()
Out[27]: '{"LoadDate":{"0":1412121600000,"1":1412208000000,...}}'
```

So the numbers you see are unix epoch timestamps. But there is a `date_format` argument to `to_json` where you can also specify to output ISO formatted strings:

```
In [19]: df.to_json(date_format='iso')
Out[19]: '{"LoadDate":{"0":"2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","1":"2014-10-02T00:00:00.000Z", ...}}'
```

---

Then, secondly, why the parsing with `read_json` is different. Again, from the [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html):

> **convert_dates** : boolean, default True
>          List of columns to parse for dates; If True, then try to parse datelike columns default is True

This is True by default, and so will try to detect datelike columns. Apparantly, this detection also looks at the column name. But as the docstring says, you can also manually specify which column should be parsed as dates:

```
In [25]: pd.read_json(df.to_json(), convert_dates=['LoadDate'])
Out[25]: 
    LoadDate  number
0 2014-10-01       0
1 2014-10-02       1
2 2014-10-03       2
3 2014-10-04       3
4 2014-10-05       4
5 2014-10-06       5
6 2014-10-07       6
```

Comment: many thanks joris - this explains most of it!! Unfortunately in my case I cannot specify which columns I need to convert to dates (above is a simplify problem), and since LoadDate originally was a datetime64[ns] I'd like it to pick this up when reading back from json. Using pandas.DataFrame.to_csv() and then pandas.DataFrame.from_csv() I can save and load a pandas dataframe with the same dates specs, what I'd like to do...is to the same in JSON. Any ideas?

Comment: In my last example, the column came back as datetime64. But also in `read_csv`, you have to specify which column you want to parse as dates (the `parse_dates` argument [there](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)), so I don't think there is a difference on this account?

Comment: you're right, doesn't make difference. I though it did - many thanks for all! :D